# MYSQL distincs entry of two columns even when switched

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

my mysql table has the following structure:

```
ID    Sender    Recipient    Text
--    ------    ---------    ----
 1    10        11           Text
 2    10        11           Text
 3    11        10           Text
 4    11        10           Text
 5    12        13           Text
 6    13        12           Text
 7    14        15           Text
 8    14        15           Text
 9    17        16           Text
10    16        17           Text
```

This table represents a private message conversation between two users. I now would like a list were i show each chat only once. Normally i would go with a group by in this case but then i still have a problem because the sender and recipient column can also be the other way around.

I would like to recieve a result like that:

```
ID    Sender    Recipient    Text
--    ------    ---------    ----
 1    10        11           Text
 2    12        13           Text
 3    14        15           Text
 4    16        17           Text
```

So each of the conversations would be unique. 
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: What wil be anchor, because there is not date, time?

Comment: The table has a time column as well. It contains the timestamp from wehn the message has been created.

Comment: How would you define one conversation? What is one conversation?

Comment: One conversation are all the entries between two user ids. So if two user ids are involved ( ie 1 + 3 ) then one conversation would be where each of the two ids is either the sender or the recipient.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. How do you get those IDs in your expected result? And what text do you want to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query like this:

```
select
  min(id) as id,
  least(sender,recipient) as sender,
  greatest(sender,recipient) as recipient
  min(text) as text
from
  tablename
group by
  least(sender,recipient),
  greatest(sender,recipient)
```

(or you can use another aggregated function for the text, like group_concat, or you have to join tablename twice to get the first or the last msg of the chat, but this depends on what you want to return)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `min(id)` and `min(text)` might come from different rows.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yes, however it's not clear from the question what's the expected content of the text column, so I don't know if a self-join or a group_concat function is more appropriate here, or if the content of the text column is not so important and can be any value

Answer (score 1):

With your sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Sender int, Recipient int, Text varchar(50), primary key (id));
INSERT INTO t (Sender, Recipient, Text) VALUES (10, 11, 'Text');
INSERT INTO t (Sender, Recipient, Text) VALUES (10, 11, 'Text');
INSERT INTO t (Sender, Recipient, Text) VALUES (11, 10, 'Text');
INSERT INTO t (Sender, Recipient, Text) VALUES (11, 10, 'Text');
INSERT INTO t (Sender, Recipient, Text) VALUES (12, 13, 'Text');
INSERT INTO t (Sender, Recipient, Text) VALUES (13, 12, 'Text');
INSERT INTO t (Sender, Recipient, Text) VALUES (14, 15, 'Text');
INSERT INTO t (Sender, Recipient, Text) VALUES (14, 15, 'Text');
INSERT INTO t (Sender, Recipient, Text) VALUES (17, 16, 'Text');
INSERT INTO t (Sender, Recipient, Text) VALUES (16, 17, 'Text');
```

You can write this query:

```
SELECT id, Sender, Recipient, Text
FROM t
JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(id) as last_id,
                CASE WHEN Sender < Recipient THEN CONCAT_WS('-', Sender, Recipient)
                     ELSE CONCAT_WS('-', Recipient, Sender)
                END as conversation
        FROM t
        GROUP BY conversation
    ) as t2 ON t2.last_id = t.id
;
```

The output is:

```
+------+----------+-------------+--------+
|   id |   Sender |   Recipient | Text   |
|------+----------+-------------+--------|
|    4 |       11 |          10 | Text   |
|    6 |       13 |          12 | Text   |
|    8 |       14 |          15 | Text   |
|   10 |       16 |          17 | Text   |
+------+----------+-------------+--------+
4 rows in set
```