# Getting the last message between users like facebook

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a messaging app that I want to display messages like facebook, it should get the last send message by either the sender or recipient, my table layout is like this:

`messages_tbl`

```
 __________________________________________________________________________
 |id | user1Fk| user2Fk |subject | user1Delete | user2Delete | dateCreated |
```

and my `user_tbl`

```
 _______________________________________
 | id | first_name | last_name | image |
```

my Query

```
SELECT `id` , `user1Fk` as sender_id, 
        (SELECT concat(first_name,\" \",last_name) 
        FROM user_tbl 
        WHERE user_tbl.id = sender_id
        ) as senderName,  
        `user2Fk` as recipient_id ,
        (SELECT concat(first_name,\" \",last_name) 
        FROM user_tbl 
        WHERE user_tbl.id = recipient_id
        ) as recipientName, 
        (SELECT image 
        FROM user_tbl 
        WHERE user_tbl.id = sender_id
        ) as senderImage, 
        (SELECT image 
        FROM user_tbl 
        WHERE user_tbl.id = recipient_id
        ) as recipientImage,
        `subject`, `message`, `user1Delete`, `user2Delete`, 
        `dateCreated` 
    FROM `message_tbl`as m1 
    WHERE dateCreated = (SELECT MAX(m2.dateCreated) 
                        from message_tbl as m2 
                        WHERE (m1.user1Fk = m2.user1Fk 
                               AND m1.user2Fk = m2.user2Fk 
                               OR m1.user1Fk = m2.user2Fk 
                               AND m1.user2Fk = m2.user1Fk
                              )
                        ) AND ? IN (m1.user1Fk, m1.user2Fk) 
    ORDER BY dateCreated DESC
```

This query is working for the most part but its lacking, I want it to check, if the given id by the `?` matches `user1Fk` it should then check if `user1Delete` is a 0 or 1, if its a 1 then do not display the message `user 1` deleted it, the same with user 2 but I cannot think of the logic, can anyone help me?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740768/mysql-distincs-entry-of-two-columns-even-when-switched/42740903#42740903

Comment: almost, but mine can select already, I just need help with checking if a message has been deleted or not before returning it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the question mark is there because this is a prepared query and the question mark should be replaced with a user id.

Your query is a little bit over complicated because there are a lot of subselects. I tried to improve it a bit for better performance and to be able to extend it easier. With SQL you can join tables instead of using subqueries, this is better for performance, and it makes it easier to add conditions to the joined tables.

In the example below I added a condition for both the user1 and user2 delete fields to be 0. I set the limit to 1, which means only the first row will be returned. Together with the descending order of the date, this means that only the newest message will be returned. I also changed the question mark to *:user_id* because in this example it is used twice and this way you'll only have to add it once.

```
SELECT 
    m.id, 
    u1.id AS sender_id, 
    CONCAT(u1.first_name, ' ', u1.last_name) AS senderName, 
    u2.id AS recipient_id, 
    CONCAT(u2.first_name, ' ', u2.last_name) AS recipientName,
    u1.image AS senderImage,
    u2.image AS recipientImage,
    m.subject, 
    m.message, 
    m.user1Delete, 
    m.user2Delete, 
    m.dateCreated
FROM messages_tbl m
INNER JOIN user_tbl u1 ON m.user1Fk = u1.id
INNER JOIN user_tbl u2 ON m.user2Fk = u2.id
WHERE (m.user1Delete = 0 AND u1.id = :user_id)
OR (m.user2Delete = 0 AND u2.id = :user_id)
ORDER BY m.dateCreated DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I haven't been able to test it but I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: the query is good but in the case user1delete is 1 it will not show the message even when user1 id is not the given id

Comment: Ah right. What about this?

    WHERE (m.user1Delete = 0 AND u1.id = :user_id)
    OR (m.user2Delete = 0 AND u2.id = :user_id)
    ORDER BY m.dateCreated DESC
    LIMIT 1